# I get an error when I import PyMC and it is not very informative, any suggestion?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pymc3, pymc

I am on Python 3.9.7 and PyMC version 5.3.0. When I do `import pymc as pm`, I get the following error. Any feedbacks would appreciated, thanks in advance.

```
import pymc as pm
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\david\AppData\Local\Temp\2\ipykernel_16476\1912255939.py", line 1, in <cell line: 1>
    import pymc as pm

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\__init__.py", line 49, in <module>
    from pymc import _version, gp, ode, sampling

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\gp\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pymc.gp import cov, mean, util

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\gp\util.py", line 30, in <module>
    from pymc.distributions.distribution import Distribution

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\distributions\__init__.py", line 15, in <module>
    from pymc.distributions.bound import Bound

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\distributions\bound.py", line 23, in <module>
    from pymc.distributions.continuous import BoundedContinuous, bounded_cont_transform

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\distributions\continuous.py", line 80, in <module>
    from pymc.distributions.dist_math import (

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\distributions\dist_math.py", line 39, in <module>
    from pymc.distributions.shape_utils import to_tuple

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\distributions\shape_utils.py", line 37, in <module>
    from pymc.model import modelcontext

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\model.py", line 66, in <module>
    from pymc.initial_point import make_initial_point_fn

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\initial_point.py", line 29, in <module>
    from pymc.util import get_transformed_name, get_untransformed_name, is_transformed_name

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\pymc\util.py", line 20, in <module>
    import arviz

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\arviz\__init__.py", line 34, in <module>
    from .plots import *

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\arviz\plots\__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
    from .autocorrplot import plot_autocorr

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\arviz\plots\autocorrplot.py", line 7, in <module>
    from .plot_utils import default_grid, filter_plotters_list, get_plotting_function

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\arviz\plots\plot_utils.py", line 15, in <module>
    from ..stats.density_utils import kde

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\arviz\stats\__init__.py", line 4, in <module>
    from .diagnostics import *

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\arviz\stats\diagnostics.py", line 15, in <module>
    from .stats_utils import _circular_standard_deviation, _sqrt

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\arviz\stats\stats_utils.py", line 537, in <module>
    def _sqrt(a_a, b_b):

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\arviz\utils.py", line 305, in conditional_vect
    return wrapper(function)

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\arviz\utils.py", line 298, in wrapper
    numba = importlib.import_module("numba")

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\numba\__init__.py", line 43, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc import (vectorize, guvectorize, threading_layer,

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\__init__.py", line 3, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc.decorators import Vectorize, GUVectorize, vectorize, guvectorize

  File "C:\Users\david\Anaconda3\envs\dev\lib\site-packages\numba\np\ufunc\decorators.py", line 3, in <module>
    from numba.np.ufunc import _internal

SystemError: initialization of _internal failed without raising an exception
```